# Different results BigQuery and Tableau

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api, visualization, calculation

Hello guys when i try to calculate median and average in my BigQuery and Tableau i get different results even though I am using same numbers and rows. Is there something I should know?

For example;

In BiQuery

select district, avg(sales) from table name

In Tableau

Using district as dimension and select average of sales from the maxcard drop down menu.

Surprisingly the output from the two are not the same.

Any one knows what might be a problem that I should know?

Thanks!

Comment: How big are the differences (some aggregates in BQ are approximate by default)? Also are you sure you are consistently comparing mean and median?

Comment: Hi matt_black just got the solution, because in Tableau i made a join with polygon data when this happens it duplicates the data in the Tableau hence different results.

Comment: Joins are always confusing and require care when doing aggregates! BTW you should post the comment as an answer as this will help other readers.

Answer (score -1):

Hi matt_black just got the solution, because in Tableau i made a join with polygon data when this happens it duplicates the data in the Tableau hence different results.

Comment: you should better not post edits as answers.  comment on your question instead, or edit it.

Comment: should be a comment